# Implementation support v-13 and v-7 in gradle Android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

I'm trying to use tensorflow lite in android and i have to implement implements FragmentCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback in a class.

I've read that i should to write in gradle this:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:version_of_library'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
```

i've added this in my gradle but there is an error in this lines and this:

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
```

This is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "midlaboratories.reconocimientoconcamara"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation project(':openCVLibrary340')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:version_of_library'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
}
```

Somebody knows a solution?

Comment: Try this:   implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:1.10.0'

Comment: I've tryed this, but the errors still are in : implementation  'com.android.support:support-v13:version_of_library',
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0 and androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'

Comment: for `compileSdkVersion 28`, the right versions of the compat libraries is from the 28 series as well. See https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages the current version is `28.0.0` for both `appcompat-v7` and `support-v13`. `version_of_library` is not a version but someone hinting at the fact that you should put a proper version there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this settings:

```
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:1.10.0' 
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0' 
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

instead of this

```
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:version_of_library'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
```